# Saving a web page as image

Tags: java, javascript, c++, html, image

As a hobby project I am exploring the ways to save a web page (HTML) as image, **mostly programatically** using c/c++/javascript/java. Till now I have come across the following ways:

1. Get the `IHTMLElement` of page body and use it to query for `IHTMLElementRender` and then use its `DrawToDC` method (**Ref:** http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/htmlimagecapture.aspx ). But the problem is that it did not work for all the pages (mostly pages having embedded iframes).
2. Another way which i can think of is to use some web browser component and when the pages is fully loaded then capture it using `BitBlt` (**Ref:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28VS.85%29.aspx ). But the problem is that the page I have requested may be longer than my screen size and it will not fit into the web browser component.

Any direction/suggestion to resolve above issues or an alternative approach is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Well finally able to crack it by going through these two articles:</strike>

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/WebPageSnapshot.aspx   [c# code - IE]
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/IECapture.aspx    [c++ & GDI - IE]

Can't share the code, but the above two articles will give you the best possible solution.

Also have a look at:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3408/    [firefox + javascript]

Above things are still ok. BUT not guaranteed to work always. Check the below link:
[How do I render the scrollable regions of a canvas with IViewObject::Draw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159607/how-do-i-render-the-scrollable-regions-of-a-canvas-with-iviewobjectdraw/2516035#2516035)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python, there's [pywebshot](https://github.com/coderholic/PyWebShot) and [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/). Both of them have some dependencies, though.

Edit: Oops, Python is not in your list of preferred languages. I'll leave this answer here anyway, because you said "mostly" and not "exclusively".

Comment: Thanks kijin .. I have considered it but in order to use it i have to learn python :)

Answer (score 1):

Another (somewhat roundabout) option would be to run a server like Tomcat and use Java to call a command-line tool to take a screenshot. Googling for "command line screenshot windows" comes up with some reasonable-looking possibilities.  Besides running a server, though, I don't know a good way to run local executables from javascript.  This method would make it cross-browser, though, which is a plus (just make an ajax call to the script when you want a screenshot).

Unfortunately I don't actually know how to deploy war files. It might be more trouble to use Tomcat; I mentioned it because Java was a preferred language. It would be fairly simple to run XAMPP and use this PHP snippet, and you wouldn't really have to learn php:

```
<?php
exec("/path/to/exec args");
?>
```

**EDIT**

You know, I'm not sure that really answers your question.  It's one way, but it's coming at it from the JavaScript end rather than the scripting end.  If you want to do it via scripting, you could always use Selenium. It supports capturing screenshots of an entire page, and can be controlled via Java.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on the use of tomcat and java here. Lets say i want to access http://stackoverflow.com then where will the tomcat piece will fit. Selenium is a nice option, will look into it.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how involved it is to deploy a web application on Tomcat. Might be easier to just use XAMPP and a PHP snippet. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK using javascript for it, I suggest going with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

Example from [http://fcargoet.evolix.net/](http://fcargoet.evolix.net/2012/01/use-phantomjs-to-take-screenshots-of-you-webapp-for-you/)

```
var page    = new WebPage(),
    address = 'http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html';

page.viewportSize = {
    width  : 800,
    height : 600
};

// define the components we want to capture
var components = [{
    output : 'feed-viewer-left.png',
    //ExtJS has a nice component query engine
    selector : 'feedpanel'
},{
    output : 'feed-viewer-preview-btn.png',
    selector : 'feeddetail > feedgrid > toolbar > cycle'
},{
    output : 'feed-viewer-collapsed.png',
    //executed before the rendering
    before : function(){
        var panel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('feedpanel')[0];
        panel.animCollapse = false; // cancel animation, no need to wait before capture
        panel.collapse();
    },
    selector : 'viewport'
}];

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {
        /*
         * give some time to ExtJS to
         *   - render the application
         *   - load asynchronous data
         */
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            components.forEach(function(component){
                //execute the before function
                component.before && page.evaluate(component.before);
                // get the rectangular area to capture
                /*
                 * page.evaluate() is sandboxed
                 * so that 'component' is not defined.
                 *
                 * It should be possible to pass variables in phantomjs 1.5
                 * but for now, workaround!
                 */
                eval('function workaround(){ window.componentSelector = "' + component.selector + '";}')
                page.evaluate(workaround);

                var rect = page.evaluate(function(){
                    // find the component
                    var comp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(window.componentSelector)[0];
                    // get its bounding box
                    var box = comp.el.getBox();
                    // box is {x, y, width, height}
                    // we want {top, left, width, height}
                    box.top  = box.y;
                    box.left = box.x;
                    return box;
                });
                page.clipRect = rect;
                page.render(component.output);
            });
            // job done, exit
            phantom.exit();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```